# $_SESSION not storing data in PHP

Tags: php, session

I developed an application using WAMP which worked perfectly. As is always the case, when I moved it onto a server it does not work.

The issue is that when I login it is meant to redirect me to the relevant page, depending on admin field in my database. Everyone receives `0` by default in the database.

This is my cutdown `login.php`

```
<?php

// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session
require("common.php");
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

// This variable will be used to re-display the user's username to them in the
// login form if they fail to enter the correct password.  It is initialized here
// to an empty value, which will be shown if the user has not submitted the form.
$submitted_username = '';
$admin = 'false';

// This if statement checks to determine whether the login form has been submitted
// If it has, then the login code is run, otherwise the form is displayed
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // This query retreives the user's information from the database using
    // their username.
    $query = "
            SELECT
                id,
                username,
                password,
                salt,
                email,
                admin,
                name,
                sso
            FROM users
            WHERE
                username = :username
        ";

    // The parameter values
    $query_params = array(
        ':username' => $_POST['username']
    );

    try {
        // Execute the query against the database
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    // This variable tells us whether the user has successfully logged in or not.
    // We initialize it to false, assuming they have not.
    // If we determine that they have entered the right details, then we switch it to true.
    $login_ok = false;

    // Retrieve the user data from the database.  If $row is false, then the username
    // they entered is not registered.
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row) {
        // Using the password submitted by the user and the salt stored in the database,
        // we now check to see whether the passwords match by hashing the submitted password
        // and comparing it to the hashed version already stored in the database.
        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']);
        for ($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) {
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']);
        }

        if ($check_password === $row['password']) {
            // If they do, then we flip this to true
            $login_ok = true;
        }
    }

    // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page
    // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again
    if ($login_ok) {
        $admin = $row['admin'];
        // Here I am preparing to store the $row array into the $_SESSION by
        // removing the salt and password values from it.  Although $_SESSION is
        // stored on the server-side, there is no reason to store sensitive values
        // in it unless you have to.  Thus, it is best practice to remove these
        // sensitive values first.
        unset($row['salt']);
        unset($row['password']);

        // This stores the user's data into the session at the index 'user'.
        // We will check this index on the private members-only page to determine whether
        // or not the user is logged in.  We can also use it to retrieve
        // the user's details.
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
        $_SESSION['admin'] = $row;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row;
        $_SESSION['sso'] = $row;


        ob_start();

        // Redirect the user to the private members-only page.
        if ($admin == 1) {
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://ocat.uat.cse.comfin.ge.com/notifcation%20system/outageNotification.php">';
            //header("Location: admin.php");
        }

        if ($admin == 0) {
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://ocat.uat.cse.comfin.ge.com/notifcation%20system/private2.php">';
        }
        if ($admin == 2) {
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://ocat.uat.cse.comfin.ge.com/notifcation%20system/super.php">';

            //Below is for Local
           // header("Location: super.php");
        }
        if ($admin == 3) {
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://ocat.uat.cse.comfin.ge.com/notifcation%20system/outageNotification.php">';
            //header("Location: admin.php");
        }
        if ($admin == 4) {
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://ocat.uat.cse.comfin.ge.com/notifcation%20system/super.php">';
//            header("Location:super.php");
        }

//        die("Now redirecting....");
    } else {
        // Tell the user they failed
        print("Login Failed.");

        // Show them their username again so all they have to do is enter a new
        // password.  The use of htmlentities prevents XSS attacks.  You should
        // always use htmlentities on user submitted values before displaying them
        // to any users (including the user that submitted them).  For more information:
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS_attack
        $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
}

?>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<form action="login.php" method="post">
    Username:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>"/>
    <br/><br/>
    Password:<br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" value=""/>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" value="Login"/>
</form>

</body>
```

As you can see, I had to stop using header: when I moved this over from local.

`common.php` looks like this, which contains the `sessionStart()` call. I include this on every page.

```
<?php


$username = "";
$password = "";
//$password = "";
$host = ":7780";
$dbname = "";

// UTF-8 is a character encoding scheme that allows you to conveniently store
// a wide varienty of special characters, like � or �, in your database.
// By passing the following $options array to the database connection code we
// are telling the MySQL server that we want to communicate with it using UTF-8
// See Wikipedia for more information on UTF-8:
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');

// A try/catch statement is a common method of error handling in object oriented code.
// First, PHP executes the code within the try block.  If at any time it encounters an
// error while executing that code, it stops immediately and jumps down to the
// catch block.  For more detailed information on exceptions and try/catch blocks:
// http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php
try {
    // This statement opens a connection to your database using the PDO library
    // PDO is designed to provide a flexible interface between PHP and many
    // different types of database servers.  For more information on PDO:
    // http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // If an error occurs while opening a connection to your database, it will
    // be trapped here.  The script will output an error and stop executing.
    // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
    // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code
    // (like your database username and password).
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

// This statement configures PDO to throw an exception when it encounters
// an error.  This allows us to use try/catch blocks to trap database errors.
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// This statement configures PDO to return database rows from your database using an associative
// array.  This means the array will have string indexes, where the string value
// represents the name of the column in your database.
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// This block of code is used to undo magic quotes.  Magic quotes are a terrible
// feature that was removed from PHP as of PHP 5.4.  However, older installations
// of PHP may still have magic quotes enabled and this code is necessary to
// prevent them from causing problems.  For more information on magic quotes:
// http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php
if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array)
    {
        foreach ($array as &$value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value);
            } else {
                $value = stripslashes($value);
            }
        }
    }

    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST);
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET);
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE);
}


// This tells the web browser that your content is encoded using UTF-8
// and that it should submit content back to you using UTF-8
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

// This initializes a session.  Sessions are used to store information about
// a visitor from one web page visit to the next.  Unlike a cookie, the information is
// stored on the server-side and cannot be modified by the visitor.  However,
// note that in most cases sessions do still use cookies and require the visitor
// to have cookies enabled.  For more information about sessions:
// http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php
session_start();

// Note that it is a good practice to NOT end your PHP files with a closing PHP tag.
// This prevents trailing newlines on the file from being included in your output,
// which can cause problems with redirecting users.
```

When I sign in, I am told I do not have permissions to view my page. When I do a `vardump` of the session, I see that it is null:

```
    <?php


    // First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session
    require("common.php");

    // At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not
    if (empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
        // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page.
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://ocat.uat.cse.comfin.ge.com/notifcation%20system/login.php">';

        // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it,
        // people can view your members-only content without logging in.
        die("Redirecting to login.php");
    }
    if(($_SESSION['user']['admin']==1)||($_SESSION['user']['admin']==2)){
        die("you do not have permission to view this page. Please press the back button in your browser.");
    }
    // Everything below this point in the file is secured by the login system

    // We can display the user's username to them by reading it from the session array.  Remember that because
    // a username is user submitted content we must use htmlentities on it before displaying it to the user.
    $con = mysql_connect(", "", "");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

I have confirmed in my database that logging in the user has an `admin` value of `0` and should be able to see the page, as I did in localhost. Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: Check the return value of session_start(). if something's prevent the session from starting, it'll return a boolean false.

Comment: then check session_id() each time. as long as you're not using session_regenerate_id, the ID value should remain constant. If it's changing, then you've got a session cookie problem and getting a brand new clean session each time.

Comment: I would recommend activating error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT) to debug any prior non obvious errors.

Comment: shouldn't you do the session start earlier? Specifically, before you send that `header`?

Comment: You are correct Nanne. However, it only gives a warning and shouldn't affect it working.

Comment: Moved it above the header call- still same issue.

Comment: Would appreciate any more help on this.